# Como chamar um método para dentro de um If e Else?

Tags: java, swing, mvc, if, else

Estou desenvolvendo um software para uma videolocadora com design pattern MVC (Model-view-controller) e está ocorrendo o problema de não chamar o método salvar() e o metodo alterar() para dentro do If e Else no botão Salvar. Se a variavel tipocadastro for "novo" ele salva e se a variavel tipocadastro for "alteração" ele altera. Já tentei varias formas e não consegui encontra a solução..e alguém aí poderia me ajudar ? Desde já, agradeço!

Classe VideoPessoa, da camada view:

```
public class VideoPessoa extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    PessoaController pessoaController;
    Pessoa pessoa;
    String tipoCadastro;

    /**
     * Creates new form Pessoa
     */
    public VideoPessoa() {
        initComponents();

        new Conexao();
        pessoaController = new PessoaController();
        pessoa = new Pessoa();
        this.carregarPessoas();// Fica sublinhado em vermelho indicando erro!
         this.novaPessoa();// Fica sublinhado em vermelho indicando erro!
        this.habilitarCampos();// Fica sublinhado em vermelho indicando erro!   
    }
```

Botão de salvar e o botão de alterar, dentro da camada view:

```
       private void btnSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
                    // TODO add your handling code here:

                    if (tipoCadastro.equals("novo")){
                        salvarPessoa();// Fica sublinhado vermelho indicando erro!

                    } else if(tipoCadastro.equals("alteracao")){

                        alteraPessoa(); // Fica sublinhado vermelho indicando erro!
                  }
            }  
        }                                         

     private void btnAlterarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
                    // TODO add your handling code here:
                    novaPessoa();
                    habilitarCampos();
                    recuperarPessoas();
                    tipoCadastro = "alteracao";
                }  
         private void novaPessoa(){
                habilitarCampos();

                txtCodigo.setText("Novo");
                txtNome.setText("");
                txtEndereco.setText("");
                txtBairro.setText("");
                txtCidade.setText("");
                txtCPF.setText("");
                txtUF.setText("");
                txtTelefone.setText("");
                txtCelular.setText("");
                txtSexo.setText("");
                tipoCadastro = "novo";
            }  


 public boolean alterarPessoa() {
        pessoa.setCodigo( Integer.parseInt(this.txtCodigo.getText()));
        pessoa.setNome(this.txtNome.getText());
        pessoa.setEndereco(this.txtEndereco.getText());
        pessoa.setBairro(this.txtBairro.getText());
        pessoa.setCPF(this.txtCPF.getText());
        pessoa.setSexo(this.txtSexo.getText());
        pessoa.setUf(this.txtUF.getText());
        pessoa.setCelular(this.txtCelular.getText());
        pessoa.setTelefone(this.txtTelefone.getText());
        pessoa.setCidade(this.txtCidade.getText());

// Aqui executo um teste se altera e quando exibe esse teste os dados não ficam alteradose e sempre exibe a mensagem alterados com sucesso!

          Integer codigo = pessoa.getCodigo();
         String nome = pessoa.getNome();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Código:"+codigo+ "nome:"+nome);

        if (pessoaController.alterar(pessoa)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registro alterado com sucesso!");
             this.desabilitarCampos();
            this.carregarPessoas();
            return true;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao alterar os dados!", "ERRO", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          return false;
        }



    }
```

Comment: Qual erro indica sublinhado?

Comment: if (salvarPessoa()){ // faça alguma coisa } if (alterarPessoa()){ // faça alguma coisa } Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas seria isso?

Comment: @rray Esse erro : `cannot find symbol `

Comment: Oi, uma vez eu li que em java o equals compara tipo de dados e não o valor que esta dentro da variável, tente mudar a comparação para == Exemplo: tipoCadastro == "novo", Verifica se funciona assim.

Comment: Esse seu método salvarPessoa(); vem da onde?

Comment: @Techies  De dentro da camada view e mesmo assim não chama o metodo salvar() e nem alterar(), por que?

Comment: Ele não chama ou está dando erro? Pois no comentário você diz que está com erro

Comment: Ele não chama e fica sublinhado de vermelho indicando que alguma coisa esta errada e quando passo o ponteiro do mouse em cima, ele exibe a mensagem: `cannot find symbo`!

Comment: Pelo que notei tem uma `}` a mais no seu método

Comment: @Techies Eu tirei essa aspa e chamo os métodos sem essa aspa..4 dias inteiros perdidos só por causa de uma aspa!

Comment: @Techies Valeu e nem mesmo assim altera os dados da minha pessoa..

Comment: Posta seu método alterar que eu tento ajudar

Comment: @Techies Atualizei minha pergunta..

Comment: Quando voce clica em alterar os campos da pessoa estão preenchidos?

Comment: Quando clico sim por que coloco palavras para mim altera.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31199/discussion-between-techies-and-igor-contini).

Answer (score 1):

Bom, a priori vejo que toda vez que você aciona o botão de Alterar Pessoa, você chama antes o `novaPessoa()`, que, no caso, limpa todos os campos e nao alteraria seu objeto. Então não o chame antes de alterar a pessoa.

Outro detalhe que, nesse caso, é melhor utilizar um booleano, que ocupa menos memoria que uma `String` e não há problemas de comparação (uma `String` em upperCase é diferente de uma `String` em lowerCase).

Ficando algo dessa forma:

```
public class BlaBlaBla { 
    boolean alterarPessoa = false;

  private void btnAlterarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
     habilitarCampos();
     recuperarPessoas();
     alterarPessoa = true;
  }

  private void novaPessoa(){
   habilitarCampos();

   txtCodigo.setText("Novo");
   txtNome.setText("");
   txtEndereco.setText("");
   txtBairro.setText("");
   txtCidade.setText("");
   txtCPF.setText("");
   txtUF.setText("");
   txtTelefone.setText("");
   txtCelular.setText("");
   txtSexo.setText("");
   alterarPessoa = false;
 } 

  private void btnSalvarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
          if (!alterarPessoa){
              salvarPessoa();
          } else {
              alteraPessoa();
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acabei de achar em um outro forum um problema igual ao meu! To fazendo reaproveitamento de código, ou seja, ctrl+c e ctrl+v de um colega meu, mas eu não sabia que ele tinha copiado o código dele na internet e achei o código que ele tinha copiado. Além disso eu não sabia que meu colega tinha copiado um trecho de um código de um outro forúm eai o dono do código estava encontrando o mesmo problema do que eu que é de não altera os dados da minha pessoa..e nem achei a solução..Segue o link : [http://www.guj.com.br/java/253029-update-de-registros-no-banco-de-dados-mysql-nao-realiza-a-alteracao]

Comment: Entendi, é bom sempre procurar na internet pontos específicos de ajuda, códigos completos costumam ser cheios de problemas. Quando somos iniciantes, é comum que nao saibamos julgar um código em uma linguagem que não dominamos, daí para cair em codigos com más práticas, más implementações e futuros problemas, é muito simples. Basta um Copiar/Colar. Espero que a resposta te ajude a entender um pouco mais e a corrigir o problema. Boas implementações!

Comment: Valeu cara! Pelos menos achei a resposta e vou implementar meu código e fazer as devidas correições necessárias a partir da sua resposta e da outra resposta do outro fórum!